# Como adicionar e remover campos gerados via CakePHP, dinamicamente?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

Olá.

Tenho um `<select>` que é alimentado por dados do banco de dados. Preciso manipular esse select e multiplicar ele caso o usuário deseje enviar dois dados diferentes. Como os `<option>`s dependem dos dados que vem do banco, não tenho a opção de usar `$(elemento).append('<select>...</select>');`

Preciso também alterar o atributo "name" de cada `<select>` para poder pegar os valores corretamente no `$this->request->data`.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-11">
        <select class="form-control name="data[Model][0][sl_dinamica]" select-a-ser-replicada">
            <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
            <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
            <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
        </select>
        <span class="btn-apagar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <span class="btn-adicionar"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Já tem algum HTML? então a ideia é quando o utilizador carregar num botão -> criar uma cópia do select na página com outro nome?

Comment: A idéia é exatamente essa. O HTML disso é gerado por um helper do próprio CakePHP. De qualquer forma é um select simples.

Comment: E já tem algum HTML para podermos usar na resposta? (e já agora está a fazer isso com AJAX? se _sim_ coloque esse código também)

Comment: `<div class="form-group">`
    `<div class="col-lg-5"><select class="form-control">                                                                                <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
<option value="2">Valor 2</option>
<option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select><span class="btn-apagar"></span></div>
</div>`

Comment: Boa! dá para colocar esse HTML na pergunta? assim outros podem ver também. Eles devem ficar dentro da mesma `<form>` suponho. A ter um novo `select` nesse HTML ele deve ficar dentro de `<div class="col-lg-5">` também?

Comment: Pode ser dentro, fora, onde for. Minha maior dificuldade é para conseguir replicar esse select com outro "name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar assim:

```
$('.btn-duplicar').on('click', function(){
    var select = $(this).parent().prev().find('select:first'); // ir buscar o original
    var novoSelect = select.clone().attr('name', 'novo_select'); // criar uma cópia e mudar o nome
    $(select).after(novoSelect); // inserir depois do select original
});
```

Algumas decisões vai você ter de tomar:

- no exemplo dei "novo_select" como nome do novo select. Pode mudar como vai gerar isso, caso gere mais do que um duplicado
- criei um botão para o duplicar, você talvez tenha outro que não mostrou na pergunta. Se ele não fôr irmão/sibling do select diga para eu ajustar a resposta.
- caso o próprio botão "duplicar" seja adicionado dinamicamente deve usar delegação. Pode substituir a primeira linha por:

  `$(document).on('click', '.btn-duplicar', function(){`

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/yx3t70dp/2/

Comment: Adaptei agora a resposta ao HTML que colocou na pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, vou testar o conceito aqui. O seu fiddle ta com um bug que fica multiplicando esse select muitas vezes, mas sua resposta me ajudou muito. Se eu conseguir posto aqui o código terminado.

Comment: @rafaslide boa, corrigi o bug, faltava usar `:first` dentro de `.find('select:first');`