# Adicionar e remover campos gerados via CakePHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp-2

Tenho um `<select>` que é alimentado por dados do banco de dados. Preciso manipular esse select e multiplicar ele caso o usuário deseje inserir mais dados diferentes.

Preciso também alterar o atributo "name" de cada `<select>` para poder pegar os valores corretamente no `$this->request->data` pois implodo os dados.

Tenho uma função que roda em php puro, mas agora estou tentando refazer no **CakePHP**. Nunca fiz nada com *Javascript* ou *Jquery* no **CakePHP**, então to meio perdido nisso.
A minha dúvida principal é sobre como utilizar Javascript com o Cake. Eu tenho um arquivo script.js que eu utilizo na aplicação com php puro. Agora quero utilizar isso com o Cakephp, mas não sei como faço. Já coloquei o arquivo na pasta webroot/js, mas não sei como fazer a partir daí.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como adicionar e remover campos gerados via CakePHP, dinamicamente?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43655/como-adicionar-e-remover-campos-gerados-via-cakephp-dinamicamente)

Comment: é parecida pois fui orientado a fazer um novo questionamento.

Comment: Paulo, talvez você possa acrescentar na sua pergunta a diferença em relação à esta outra e até mesmo esse código que você disse que possui mas deseja utilizar o `CakePHP` para isso.

Answer (score 0):

O Cakephp segue um padrão para criação dos campos do formulário, se você estiver usando o [Cake Form Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

O padrão é sempre assim:

```
$this->Form->input('model.id'); // <input type="text" name="data[model][id]" />
```

Baseando-se nesse retorno, você poderia adicionar os campos normalmente pelo jQuery, porém definindo os `name` do elemento de acordo com o padrão do Cakephp. Veja um exemplo simples

```
$(function(){
   var $form =  $('#meu-formulario');

   var $baseSelect = $('<select></select>');


     $('.algum-evento').click(function(){
         var $newSelect = $baseSelect.clone();

          $newSelect.attr({name: 'data[model][novo_campo]'});

         $form.append($newSelect);
     });

});
```

Comment: Essa pergunta foi o mais próximo do que achei sobre o meu problema:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43655/como-adicionar-e-remover-campos-gerados-via-cakephp-dinamicamente/50471?noredirect=1#comment102498_50471

Comment: pode me explicar melhor? eu estou com uma dificuldade tremenda em entender o funcionamento. O que vai no controller, se precisa alterar algo no model, como chamo a função no botão. A única coisa que fiz foi colocar um script que já tinha dentro da pasta webroot/js. Estou finalizando um projeto grande e que me tomou vários meses, só falta essa parte mesmo.